# Retrofit - JSON Array Parsing

Tags: java, android, arrays, json, retrofit

I am parsing JSON `Array` using `Retrofit`, where JSON Array looks like:

```
"hobbies": [ "Music", "Reading"]
```

Here is what my `JSON` looks like:

```
{
    "type":"success",
    "value":[
        {
            "id":1,
            "title":"Title - 1",
         "name":{
            "first":"First - 1",
            "last":"Last - 1"
         },
            "hobbies":[
                "Writing Code - 1",
            "Listening Music - 1"
            ]
        },
       .....
    ]
}
```

**Value.java**

```
private List<String> hobbies = new ArrayList<String>();
```

**Adapter.java**

```
viewHolder.hobbies.setText(value.getHobbies().toString());
```

And when I run my program, I am `getting data` as seen below:

```
[Music, Reading]
```

So, **Question** is `Why` I am getting `[]` as well in output.

**Value.java**

```
public class Value {

    @SerializedName("id")
    @Expose
    private Integer id;

    @SerializedName("title")
    @Expose
    private String title;

    @SerializedName("hobbies")
    @Expose
    private List<String> hobbies = new ArrayList<String>();

    @SerializedName("name")
    @Expose
    private Name name;

    .....

    public List<String> getHobbies() {
        return hobbies;
    }

    public void setHobbies(List<String> hobbies) {
        this.hobbies = hobbies;
    }
}
```

**Service.java**

```
public interface Service {

   @GET("/demo_retrofit.json")
   Observable<Master> getMaster();
}
```

Comment: use http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ to convert your json to pojo

Comment: @JacksonChengalai is right

Comment: but my issue is why I am getting [] in output

Comment: @Oreo Actually `value.getHobbies();` directly return an `List` with `[ ]`. better `iterate` it and show by using `StringBuilder`

Comment: @MD please post it as your answer, then I will accept that one.

Comment: @Oreo No it's fine. Always ready to help.

Comment: what is your completed json values post full data

Comment: @MD your solution helped me, for me you have to post your solution

Comment: @Oreo Ok wait bro i will post my asnwer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually `value.getHobbies();` directly return an `List` with `[ ]`. better `iterate` it and show by using `StringBuilder`

Answer (score 1):

MD and Jackson are right. `Object.toString()` method returns a string that "textually represents" this object. So for your case, hobbies is an arrayList so the textually representation will have `[]` with it. ;)

Edit:

You may want to use for loop for this:

```
for (String hobby : hobbies) {
    // Do something with hobby here
}
```

Comment: thanks and I already done with this, but sorry this time will accept @MD's answer, because he shown me the way first to get it.. :) But I ticked your answer as useful, I also used for each loop...

Comment: Try join your values together using StringBuilder, `stringBuilder.append(value)`. Then only you do `learningTV.setText(stringBuilder.toString());`

Comment: hello buddy. Look at this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35522662/retrofit-pass-string-to-fetch-json-data