# ArrayList Null Pointer Exception playing with Condition

Tags: java, android, json, retrofit

`ArrayList` NullPointerException `(NPE)` while fetching data for the product of **Google** only

Here is the line where I am getting `NPE`:

```
searchList.add(value); // getting NPE
```

**Log:**

```
02-24 14:25:35.903 17269-17269/app.retrofit_chucknorries E/app.retrofit_chucknorries.MainActivity$2: ERROR: null
02-24 14:25:35.904 17269-17269/app.retrofit_chucknorries W/System.err: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-24 14:25:35.909 17269-17269/app.retrofit_chucknorries W/System.err:     at app.retrofit_chucknorries.MainActivity.searchList(MainActivity.java:132)
02-24 14:25:35.909 17269-17269/app.retrofit_chucknorries W/System.err:     at app.retrofit_chucknorries.MainActivity$1.call(MainActivity.java:57)
02-24 14:25:35.909 17269-17269/app.retrofit_chucknorries W/System.err:     at app.retrofit_chucknorries.MainActivity$1.call(MainActivity.java:51)
02-24 14:25:35.909 17269-17269/app.retrofit_chucknorries W/System.err:     at rx.Observable$32.onNext(Observable.java:7187)
02-24 14:25:35.909 17269-17269/app.retrofit_chucknorries W/System.err:     at rx.observers.SafeSubscriber.onNext(SafeSubscriber.java:130)
02-24 14:25:35.909 17269-17269/app.retrofit_chucknorries W/System.err:     at rx.internal.operators.NotificationLite.accept(NotificationLite.java:150)
02-24 14:25:35.909 17269-17269/app.retrofit_chucknorries W/System.err:     at rx.internal.operators.OperatorObserveOn$ObserveOnSubscriber.pollQueue(OperatorObserveOn.java:189)
02-24 14:25:35.909 17269-17269/app.retrofit_chucknorries W/System.err:     at rx.internal.operators.OperatorObserveOn$ObserveOnSubscriber.access$000(OperatorObserveOn.java:65)
02-24 14:25:35.910 17269-17269/app.retrofit_chucknorries W/System.err:     at rx.internal.operators.OperatorObserveOn$ObserveOnSubscriber$2.call(OperatorObserveOn.java:153)
02-24 14:25:35.910 17269-17269/app.retrofit_chucknorries W/System.err:     at rx.internal.schedulers.ScheduledAction.run(ScheduledAction.java:47)
02-24 14:25:35.910 17269-17269/app.retrofit_chucknorries W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:808)
02-24 14:25:35.910 17269-17269/app.retrofit_chucknorries W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
02-24 14:25:35.910 17269-17269/app.retrofit_chucknorries W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
02-24 14:25:35.910 17269-17269/app.retrofit_chucknorries W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5299)
02-24 14:25:35.910 17269-17269/app.retrofit_chucknorries W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-24 14:25:35.910 17269-17269/app.retrofit_chucknorries W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
02-24 14:25:35.910 17269-17269/app.retrofit_chucknorries W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:829)
02-24 14:25:35.910 17269-17269/app.retrofit_chucknorries W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:645)
02-24 14:25:35.911 17269-17269/app.retrofit_chucknorries W/System.err:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**JSON**

```
{
   "type":"success",
   "value":[
      {
         "id":1,
         "title":"Nexus 9",
         "product":"Google"
      },
      {
         "id":2,
         "title":"iPhone 6S",
         "product":"Apple"
      },
      {
         "id":3,
         "title":"iPhone 5",
         "product":"Apple"
      },
      {
         "id":4,
         "title":"Nexus 7",
         "product":"Google"
      }
   ]
}
```

Now, I just want to `fetch data` for the `product` **Google**

```
public void searchList() {

        if(searchList != null && !searchList.isEmpty()) {
            searchList.clear();
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < valueList.size(); i++) {
            value = (Value) valueList.get(i);

            String strProduct = valueList.get(i).getProduct();

            if (strProduct.equalsIgnoreCase(strSearch)){
                  searchList.add(value); // getting NPE
            }
        }

        mAdapter = new MainAdapter(searchList, R.layout.card_row, getApplicationContext());
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    }
```

Comment: What exactly is the issue?

Comment: I just need to get data that relates to product Google as you can see my json I have an object named product

Comment: How does your `Master` model look?

Comment: Sorry, I presume the `Master` looks like the `JSON`.

Comment: I posted both Master and Value model classes, please check now

Comment: Are you getting results from the server on the device?

Comment: Dont you need a `CallAdapter` and a `Converter`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you never instantiate your list to use. I think changing your method like this will fix your issue:

```
public void searchList() {

     if (searchList == null) {
         searchList = new ArrayList<>();
     } else {
         searchList.clear();
     }

     for (int i = 0; i < valueList.size(); i++) {
       ...
     }

     mAdapter = new MainAdapter(searchList, R.layout.card_row, getApplicationContext());
     mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

}
```

Answer (score -1):

The `Exception` that you are talking about only came when it Variable `searchList` doesn't referring to `Object` of List rather it refers to `null`. So, you should **debug** the **code** and find out that is `List` **object** `searchList` actually referring to null or not? If it is so **Instantiate** `searchList` at that particular **line** using `new` **Keyword**.

> **Note** :- Dubug Your application may short-out your Problem...